# Desktop file uploader for a website

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, desktop-application, multiple-file-upload, large-file-upload

I'm writing an upload functionality for a website (Javascript, ASP.NET). The requirement is that the user would upload a large folder of multiple files (~20k files having ~3GB in total). We would like to save the user from most of the trouble with reuploading failed files.

I've seen that some websites allow you to download **desktop app** for uploading and downloading files. I'd like to write something similar. I've been doing some research on the internet but I can only find JavaScript/Flash/etc. web solutions for that.

Do you know any tutorials on how to do it? Or maybe some article which explains possible ways of implementing that. Do you think my approach is good or should I invest some time in web solution instead of desktop app?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dropzone](http://www.dropzonejs.com). İt seems useful to file upload functionalities